# Negative voltage output Or Controling negative voltage

Tags: arduino-nano, rgb-led

I've got an RGB led strip I'm trying to control. It's a 12v, 4 pin strip. 
Pin layout seems rather odd to me as 1 pin takes 12v of power and 3 pins (that go to ground) control the colors. In other words, **the LED colors are controlled by limiting outgoing voltage**.

[image: Led Strip]

- **White**- +12v
- **Green**- Green in negative voltage
- **Red** - Red in negative voltage
- **Blue** - Blue in negative voltage

I've already made a similar setup that uses n-channel MOSFETS (or at least I think that's what they are) between the colored cables and the ground and Arduino power the MOSFET gates as necessary.

**So my question is:** is it possible to hook these LEDs up directly to arduino and control the negative voltage without aditional electronics?

As a slightly off topic question: Is there a specific name for elements that are controlled with negative voltages.

---

By the way, I'm using Arduino nano, although I don't think it is relevant at this point and I've got Mega and Uno aswell if needed.

Comment: It seemed weird to me too, at first. But you'll find out it actually makes it a lot easier to connect. Switching the cathode side only requires an n-channel transistor/mosfet, which you can drive directly from 5v arduino pins. Switching the anode side would require additional components since the transistor/mosfets would require 12v signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible, since the voltages and currents involved (12V) are too high.  It will damage your board.

Your arrangement with N-channel MOSFETs is the correct arrangement.

By the way, you are not working with "negative" voltages at all - it's all positive - you just happen to be between the "load" and ground.

This is called a **Low Side Switch** since it is on the "low" (i.e., between the load and ground) side of the circuit.

The LEDs you have are in an arrangement called **Common Anode** in that the anodes (+ pins) of the LEDs are all tied together (common) and you control the cathode (- pins) of the LEDs.  It means you can use cheap N-channel MOSFETs that are (as you have seen) easy to control with a microcontroller.  The other arrangement, *Common Cathode*, where all the cathodes (- pins) are tied together and you switch the power to the anodes (+ pins) requires P-channel MOSFETs *and* N-channel MOSFETs to switch the P-channel MOSFETs, which increases costs.

Comment: Just for the reference If I used 5v LEDs would it be possible then?

Comment: If you used 5V LEDs and the total current for all the LEDs on one colour channel was below around 20mA then yes it would be possible.

Comment: I'm still far from understanding the limits of arduino, but. I just checked the leds. They are just under 4mA/channel.
Wouldn't that work with VIN pin powered arduino?

Comment: Then if they are 5V LEDs you can run around 5 channels in parallel without any extra hardware. Any more than that and you will need the MOSFETs regardless to handle the extra current.

Comment: It doesn't have to be MOSFETs, a bog-standard cheap NPN BC547 or similar would be fine.